# How to display the title of the element on which I hovered in the console

Tags: reactjs

I have a list that has a "text" field. I display the list on the page. And each element has an onMouseEnter event.

I need to display the text of the element I hovered over when hovering over an element. Now the entire list is displayed in the console. How can i do this?

```js
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "Text1",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "Text2",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "Text3",
        },
      ],
    };

    this.hoverHandler = this.hoverHandler.bind(this);
  }

  hoverHandler() {
    console.log(this.state.list);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map((item) => (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              onMouseEnter={this.hoverHandler}
            >
              {item.text}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'd need to identify which element is hovered.  For example, you can pass an identifier to the handler function:

```
onMouseEnter={() => this.hoverHandler(item.id)}
```

Then in that function use that identifier to find the one record you want:

```
hoverHandler(id) {
  console.log(this.state.list.find(x => x.id === id));
}
```

If you just want to display one property on that array item, then just display that one property:

```
hoverHandler(id) {
  console.log(this.state.list.find(x => x.id === id)?.text);
}
```